# How to do Asynchronous call to a function in C++ (VS 2008)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, asynchronous

How to create an asynchronous function in C++ in Visual Studio 2008 (.NET 3.5 Framework)? I came to know that

```
#include <future>
async
```

[will work for C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/).  How to achieve the same in VS 2008?

Comment: You mean, like, launch a thread and WaitForSingleObject? or you're doing this in CLI, you mean using the [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading(v=vs.110).aspx) stuff ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, I can use CLI no problem in it, but I don't want to create threads, I just want to go ahead with next statements without waiting for the function call to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a program for that tell me your email id I will forward you. or otherwise you can give me test mail on qt.itk.vtk.help_gmail.com